# Get absolute path to project directory in application.properties

Tags: java, configuration, quarkus

I am writing a Quarkus application which reads data over http. In my `application.properties` file, I have this line:

```
my.resource=http://path/to/file
```

Every time I run the app, it has to download the file so I created a smaller version of the file locally for developing purpose. The problem is that I don't know how to put it in the `properties` file.

Ideally, I want something like this:

```
my.resource=http://path/to/file
%dev.my.resource=file://${project-dir}/sample_data/file
```

And I have to use the absolute path because I used `new URI(resource).toURL()` method which requires an absolute URI.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quarkus is really designed for containerized applications built into an executable JAR, and the idea of a "project directory" will make no sense at all in such a set-up. If you want to load specific resources from the application's JAR, you can probably use `ClassLoader.findResource()`. Conventionally `application.properties` is placed in the top-level directory of the JAR, which also forms the root of the classloader hierarchy.

Comment: I want to use it for dev and test profiles. I think it still makes sense to have the path to project directory in such case.

Answer (score 0):

Application properties is something that is used when your application is deployed to adopt your application to the target environment, does the user of the deployed application know anything about project directory? Project directory is something that makes sense when you are developing your application. having said that using project directory in that file does not make sense at all.

Comment: Actually, I want to use the config for testing purpose. The config for prod profile will be like this `my.resource=http://...` while that for test profile is like` %test.my.resource=file://absolute/path/to/file`. The test file is inside the project directory but I cannot use relative path.